# Rails - model update decimal - render rounded value from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rounding

I have a decimal field called label_length in my model Offer with one decimal place. The value gets rounded when saved into the database.

A record is already stored in the database. I’m in the edit form for my Offer model. Now I put 123.45 into the text field and hit the button. After saving I render the edit action again with the text field. In the text field for label_length I find the value 123.45 again although 123.5 is stored in the database.

It seems that @offer in the controller is not updated after calling offer.update_attributes(params[:offer])

Is there a way to display the current database value?

Thanks
Marc

Comment: Posting some code from the controller would probably help us help you. You have a clear picture of what the code's doing, but we don't.

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question. Particularly for how you perform the rounding of the value and how you render the edit page (the controller action code).

Answer (score 1):

What does your migration look like? You can prompt Rails to create a decimal field with a set scale and precision in your migration so that you don't have values unexpectedly rounded:

```
t.decimal :amount,  :precision => 6, :scale => 2
```

As far as getting Rails to use the data from the database after saving, you can simply add in a call to `reload` like so:

```
if @offer.save
  @offer.reload
  ...
else
  ...
end
```

Comment: @offer.reload is what I was looking for and couldn't find. Thanks a lot and kind regards Marc